# overriding function for each instance c++

Tags: c++

So, what i'm trying to do is this:
I would like to create a general class `MyCLASS` with a function `genericFunction()` which is empty by default. Now, when a co-worker wants to use this generic function, what he does is creating an instance of `MyClass`, and overriding `genericFunction()`, so it should give a resoult similar to this:

```
class MyClass{
   public:
      void genericFunction(){
         //boring default actions
      }
      //constructor
      MyClass(){
         //do things
      }
};


int main(){
   MyClass instance();
   //now we override the function, something like:
   instance.genericFunction(){
      cout << "This new code exists only for this instance, and has been created outside the class!";
   } 
   instance.genericFunction();

   return 0;
}
```

So that's basically what I would like to do.

In the case that it is not possible, how can i make my class run a function that is going to be later defined in `main()`?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:** To answer your questions:

*I'm new to c++ and it's true that my background is from other languages
*The idea is the following: You are creating objects that have a position, and if the position is in a certain range, `genericFunction()` is executed. The thing is that for each instance the function that is executed may (or in fact should) be different. The idea is 'inspired' by android's clickListener, where each element has a different function to execute when clicked

Thanks again!

Comment: Do you really need the function to be part of a class ? Why ?

Comment: Use std::function as a member, and bind a callable to it in the constructor.

Comment: You need to create an abstract class with abstract methods and instead of instancing the class you will inherit from it and the abstract method will need to be overridden

Comment: Member functions are part of the type MyClass, and C++ is statically typed -meaning you can't change a type at runtime. I feel like your background is in a very different language. If not, @arynaq's solution is valid, but somewhat advanced.

Comment: FYI `MyClass instance();` declares a function without parameters named `instance` which returns `MyClass`.

Comment: **arynaq** was on the right track, and **Gallik** completed it. @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz, inheritance is not always - or, perhaps, rarely - the right answer. If the OP really wants different functions per instance, then inheritance doesn't supply that, as it can only change behaviour on the class level. And besides, it may be excessive in the number of lines of code (and bytes of vtables, but then you just trade those for member callables anyway) that'd need written for every slight variation in behaviour, the hassle of a common base, etc. Simply storing a callable is often the right solution.

Comment: Galik's answer below and @arynaq commebt are exactly what I needed, thanks a lot everyone!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to be able to set user defined functions for a class object then you can give it a  *member variable* of type [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). Using slightly different syntax from your example it could look like this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:

    std::function<void()> genericFunction = []{};
};

int main()
{
    MyClass instance;

    instance.genericFunction(); // does nothing

    // assign a lambda function to our
    // function member
    instance.genericFunction = []
    {
        std::cout
            << "This new code exists only for this instance, and has been created outside the class!";
    };

    instance.genericFunction(); // executes our lambda function
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to be able to pass parameters or receive a return value, then change the template signature to `std::function` like this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    // take a string parameter and return an integer    
    std::function<int(std::string const&)> genericFunction = [](std::string const&){ return 0; };
};

int main()
{
    MyClass instance;

    int return_value;

    return_value = instance.genericFunction("This will do nothing and return 0"); // does nothing

    std::cout << "The first function returned: " << return_value << '\n';

    // assign a lambda function to our
    // function member
    instance.genericFunction = [](std::string const& msg)
    {
        std::cout << msg << '\n';
        return 5;
    };

    return_value = instance.genericFunction("This will pint a message and return 5"); // executes our lambda function

    std::cout << "The second function returned: " << return_value << '\n';
}
```

Comment: How can I pass parameters to genericFunction()?

Comment: @RomoloCaponera I added a second example that takes a parameter and returns an value.

Comment: is it possible to call a instance function inside `genericFunction()`? For example defining a function `anotherFunction()` into MyClass and inside `genericFunction()` calling `instance.anotherFunction();`. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Depending on your compiler, you may need to `#include <functional>` to use `std::function`.